# How to pass variables to YAML in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, http-post, azure-powershell

I have a small PowerShell script where I have hard-coded values and I would like to make it more dynamic by passing in variables. I have tried but have not been successful.

Here is a part of my PowerShell script where I would like to pass in the values for `$book` and `$author`. I am trying to make a HTTP POST request using the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet.

```bsh
$body = @{
    version = '1.0'
    inactive = 'false'
    yml = { "Service1:\n book: $book\n author: $author\n "} | ConvertFrom-Json
} | ConvertTo-Json

$request = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType

$response = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $request.Content
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @dn_learner  Perhaps reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve will provide useful information in assisting you to edit the question so that you will be more likely to receive good answers to solve your problem.

Comment: How do you wish to pass in variables? Is this to be run on the console, and your variables will be supplied as command parameters?

Comment: @halfer, Yes, for now, I am trying to run it from the console...

Comment: `@body` is not a valid variable name, and what does your question have to do with YAML? Did you mean JSON? Also, how *exactly* have you "not been successful"? Which part of your code fails? Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Comment: I've corrected @body to $body as it was just a typo when I didn't properly copy & pasted the snippet... My request payload takes a JSON object where one of the properties is a YAML as shown in the code snippet... I am not getting any errors nor does the code fail... what is not happening is that the parameters values are not being substituted for $book and $author and that is where I am seeking help... I hope I made it clear

Comment: Which parameter values? `$author` and `$book` aren't defined anywhere in your code. Also, you cannot convert a YAML string to JSON by putting it in a scriptblock and piping that into `ConvertFrom-Json`. You need a [YAML parser](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml) for the data import and then convert the PowerShell data to JSON.

Comment: @Ansgar,  the variables $author and $book are already defined as parameters in the powershell script... I didn't provide the whole script but just the snippet where I am having issues getting the values not getting substituted for those variables.... hope that helps...

Comment: The variables are not expanded because you put the string in a scriptblock. But again, your whole construct is unlikely to do what you want anyway. Please [edit] your question and show the desired JSON structure.